# How do download the latest version of Go

Tags: bash, shell, go, automation

How can I find the latest version number of Go without knowing what the exact version number is of the latest version? This in order to construct the download url.

When release is on GitHub I can do this with for example

```
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/nagios-plugins/nagios-plugins/releases/latest" | jq -r '.assets[] | .browser_download_url')
```

But as the download url's are not on GitHub but on https://golang.org/dl/ I'd love to find out how to find the latest Go version number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got this from the ml:

```
# download latest version of Go
VERSION=`curl -L https://golang.org/VERSION?m=text`
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/$VERSION.windows-amd64.msi # windows
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/$VERSION.linux-amd64.tar.gz # linux
# etc.
```

Comment: This is not correct. Use https://go.dev/dl/?mode=json instead. Today for example, go v1.18.1 (unstable!) is in use by the go.dev website, and reported by the URL of the accepted answer. The correct URL is given by https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51135.

Answer (score 3):

Use https://go.dev/dl/?mode=json to obtain the latest stable version. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51135.

The problem with using `curl https://golang.org/VERSION?m=text` is that on some days, it will give "bleeding edge" result that is not actually available for download. Like today 2022-04-12 (: It returns 1.18.1 which is not yet available for download.

For example you could use

```sh
VERSION=$(curl -s https://go.dev/dl/?mode=json | jq -r '.[0].version')
# go1.18
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem begins with the URL `https://go.dev/VERSION?m=text` is, it now returns the date time also. So storing the response of this URL as go version will not work now a days. But we can easily fix that with just a little tweaking:

```
GO_VERSION=$(curl -Ls https://go.dev/VERSION?m=text | head -n 1)
DOWNLOAD_URL="https://go.dev/dl/${GO_VERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz" # for linux
wget "${DOWNLOAD_URL}"
```

The `curl` flag `-Ls` works as follow:

- `-L` stands for "location" and it is used to handle HTTP redirects.
- `-s` flag is used for "silent" mode, which means cURL will not show progress meters or error messages.